# Brackeys Dialogue without Start Button(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've followed Brackeys Tutorial for a dialogue system but I don't want the Start Button in Unity, the text should start alone. Can anyone help me with the script? I've tried it several hours but I don't get it to work.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class DialogTrigger : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public Dialog dialog;

        public void TriggerDialogue()
        {
            FindObjectOfType<DialogManager>().StartDialog(dialog);
        }

    }
```

> Blockquote

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    public class DialogManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float delay;
        public Text nameText;
        public Text dialogueText;



        private Queue<string> sentences;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            sentences = new Queue<string>();
        }

        public void StartDialog(Dialog dialog)
        {


            nameText.text = dialog.name;

            sentences.Clear();

            foreach (string sentence in dialog.sentences)
            {
                sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
            }

            DisplayNextSentence();
        }

        public void DisplayNextSentence()
        {
            if (sentences.Count == 0)
            {
                EndDialogue();
                return;
            }

            string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
            StopAllCoroutines();
            StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
        }

        IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
        {
            dialogueText.text = "";
            foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
            {
                dialogueText.text += letter;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
            }
        }

        void EndDialogue()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        }

    }
```

I've found a comment to write in void start but it doesn't work and with a collider it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "I don't want the Start Button in Unity"? Do you mean you want to be able to trigger it from some other place instead of the Start() method?

Comment: In Brackeys tutorial, he uses a start button to "execute" the script, if he clicks the button, the dialogue starts, but i want it without the start button in unity, i want to trigger the script if i start the scene, but if i try it with the start method, an issue appears "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 2):

`DialogueManager` should setup its `Queue` in `Awake()` intsead of `Start()`:

```
public class DialogManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }
```

Then `DialogTrigger` can safely call `TriggerDialogue()` from its `Start()`:

```
public class DialogTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        TriggerDialogue();
    }
```

When a scene loads, all scripts run their `Awake()` method (if they have one), then all enabled scripts run their `Start()` method.

---

You could also choose to initialize the `Queue` in the same line you declare it:

```
public class DialogManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Queue<string> sentences = new Queue<string>();
```

Then that class doesn't need an `Awake()` or `Start()` method and `DialogTrigger` is always safe to call it.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it as soon as i am on my pc

Answer (score 1):

@Foggzie 's method really works! For those who suffer from "Null reference" problem, make sure **if you have changed the name of the script file** (In my case, I change it into"DialogueManagerAwake")

You change the name in DialogueTrigger:
`FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);`

To
`FindObjectOfType<DialogueManagerAwake>().StartDialogue(dialogue);`

Then you will get rid of the problem!